# Xcode adds duplicate constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

In code I added 4 constraints. But when I run the app, in UI debugger, it shows additional 6 constraints? It should be all clear with these 4 I added. I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

```
let leftConstr   = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let bottomConstr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView , attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let highthConstr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
let widthConstr  = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
cell.contentView.addConstraints([highthConstr, widthConstr, bottomConstr, leftConstr])
```

Here is the screenshot of my UI debugger

[image: screenshot.]

Comment: I have seen this happen as well. If I try to make my constraints programmatically, it seems like it autogenerates the ones I don't create to make the scenario work. Perhaps  'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' is what did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try to add this line of code before :

```
image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thanks @Matthias